# why don't add a comment when downvoting?

Tags: feature-request, comments, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes)

Whould it be nice to add a comment as **mandatory option** when one downvotes an answer?
First if the answer is downvoted it's considered to be a wrong so that a comment could clarify that. Second it will help detect people who misused downvoting. 
what do you think?

Comment: A "mandatory option" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: It's not a bad idea, but it should also be possible to upvote an existing comment instead of commenting yourself in case someone else already downvoted for the same reason.

Answer (score 6):

Down-voting is already done far too infrequently, and it already incurs a relatively steep penalty on the down-voter.  Why do you feel we need to de-incentivize it even more?

Plus, often times, someone has already left a comment indicating why the answer was wrong (or why the question is wretched), or **there are already correct (and higher-voted) answers** that contradict the down-voted one. The down-voted answerer doesn't need his/her hand held.

Comment: Yup. We need *more* downvoting - people are apparently *afraid* to do so, because it is not *nice*. Meh.

Comment: @Piskvor'sSemifiniteMonkeys I think many times a critical comment is far more detrimental than a downvote, as if people are afraid of upvoting a possibly incorrect answer.